# How does AOT work, where traditionally Javascript says the results of compilation are not portable among various systems

Tags: javascript, angular

How does Ahead Of Time Compilation works when the book **You Dont Know Js** clearly states the following below

> It is not compiled well in advance, as are many traditionally-compiled
>   languages, nor are the results of compilation portable among various
>   distributed systems.

[Reference for the above](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch1.md#compiler-theory)

While the AOT Documentation says..

> With AOT, the browser downloads a pre-compiled version of the
>   application. The browser loads executable code so it can render the
>   application immediately, without waiting to compile the app first.

Comment: AOT is not compilation in the same sence that javascript is compiled at run time. AOT is creating a bundle of the angular application parts that can then be "compiled" by the javascript engine at run time. For example: `*ngFor` in a template has no direct javascript equivalent, it must be compiled into javascript before it can be executed and that is what AOT does. So these are 2 very different things.